# SendInput %userInput% causes my computer to malfunction oddly

Tags: autohotkey

SendInput %userInput% causes my computer to do very weird stuff. Sometimes it logs off, sometimes my arrows of the keyboard get disabled, sometimes it runs cmd in windows an infinite times...

UPDATE:
this is the thing that gets inputed in the command line and runs: 
runas /user:administrator cmd

UPDATE:
I think I almost got the problem, as such I edited the question to leave out what I deem to be irrelevant now.
When SendInput is happening, and the user is still inputting data in the keyboard, such as pressing the win-key, then this can cause the system to log off because win-key + l is a shortcut for that. Likewise must be for all the other things that are happening. Another observation is that SendInput skips certain characters, like {enter} etc. It only processes them at the end, when all the regular characters are put into place. I notice that at the end, SendInput is still busy doing stuff, perhaps some exotic characters it delayed till the end. Because the user think the output is complete, he ends up pressing the shortcut key again which in combination with the current sendInput is causing the system to crash.

UPDATE:
It also goes bezerk if there is a "!" to be send with SendInput.
This is one string I pasted to the copyboard:
dsjkfhjdsfsjdh!!!!!!!!!!!@@@@@@@@############$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%^^^^^^^^^^^^^&&&&&&&&&&&&&*************(((((((((())))))))))))***_*__*_***++++++++++++++++=======------------000000000000000099999988888.

But the output is WITHOUT the exclamation marks. Like this:
 dsjkfhjdsfsjdh@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&*************(((((((((())))))))))))***_*__*_***+======------------000000000000000099999988888.

Why is that? Are there any other characters? Exclamation marks are important I feel, and I don't want to remove them. Are there any workarounds?

UPDATE:
It is more complicated than that. When I copy paste the above characters WITHOUT the exclamation marks, it still does weird stuff.
Here is some of the code that eventually userInput combines and sends away with SendInput:

`````
StringReplace, contents, save_selection, ``, ````, All        ; Do this replacement first to avoid interfering with the others below.

StringReplace, contents, contents, `r`n, %A_SPACE%, All       ; Using `r works better than `n in MS Word, etc.
StringReplace, contents, contents, `;, ```;, All             
;* loc_title origanally contains browser specification. Remove it.
StringGetPos, pos_delim, loc_title, - , R
length := StrLen(loc_title)
count := length - pos_delim
StringTrimRight, loc_title, loc_title, count
`````

Comment: The contents is stored in an ini filed as I mentioned above. The strange thing is that even when I reboot and don't do any action except reading from that file by pasting it's contents with a hotkey, then too it will go beserk. The first time I can paste it. The second time it goes beserk.

Comment: I think I can reduce the question now by asking: How can I prevent any further UserInput from happening as long as SendInput is in process? I don't think that is difficult.  The difficult thing is for me to find out what hidden characters are still getting outputted so I can filter them out?

Comment: The command SendInput %userinput% will process the value in the userinput variable and send it to Windows as keyboard commands.  It sounds like your issue is earlier in your script where userinput gets set.  The code that sets userinput is needed to debug the issue.  You can block input with the BlockInput command.  Win+L does not log you out, it just locks the account.

Comment: blockinput doesn't work because i have win 7, so it only works with admin rights. I tried the admin hack, but the file shellexecute is not to be found on my comp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sendraw` instead of `sendinput`.

Here is what the docs say:

> Raw mode: The SendRaw command interprets all characters **literally**
>   rather than translating {Enter} to an ENTER keystroke, ^c to
>   Control-C, etc. However, the normal rules for escape sequences,
>   variable references and expressions still apply since these are
>   processed before the command executes. To use raw mode with SendInput,
>   SendPlay, or SendEvent, write {Raw} as the first item in the string;
>   for example: SendInput {Raw}abc.

Then you don't have to worry about the `!` or other control modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the exclamation mark character is an issue is because `SendInput` treats it as a code to press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

There are several similar codes:
`^` = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
`+` = <kbd>Shift</kbd>
`#` = <kbd>Windows key</kbd>

You can find the others listed in the documentation for [SendInput](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).

It seems like you want to send the raw text and not have `SendInput` look for these codes.  You should be able to put `{Raw}` at the beginning of the `userinput` variable and it will ignore any codes in the rest of the characters.

If it is typing too slowly, you could put `SetKeyDelay,-1` in your script to remove the key sending delay.

Answer (score -4):

A good workaround that I found was to avoid SendInput altogether. Rather use the clipboard to copy the string inside, to then paste it on your screen. It works flawlessly, and is a billion times faster. Why would a person utilize SendInput in the first place? However, the actual question still is standing, why does SendInput behave so strangely? What is inside that string: %userInput% that causes my system to crash? How can I find out?

Comment: A person would use `send` or `sendinput` if he: 1) wanted to preserve the contents of his clipboard, 2) he was already using the clipboard for something else, 3) he was worried about security.  A billion times faster?  I'm not so sure about that.  Also, you can't use the clipboard to send windows+key combinations - or any other key combination for that matter.  Also, Khalil, you posted an answer - if you want to ask a question, start a new thread.

Comment: @BGM your answer is greatly appreciated. Concerning your last comment, the answer provided me a workaround that was helpful to me at the time when no better alternative was available and is merely restating the same question. Why is it encouraged to open up a new thread for that? I checked the help section but couldn't find any helpful clarification.

Comment: Well, you said, "the question still is standing..." after which you end your answer with a question - it's the same as asking a question.  Your original question will still be there until you accept someone's answer (even if it is your own answer).  Anyway, this "discussion" is out of scope here and we'll get in "trouble" if we continue it here (it's really a discussion for the meta site, you know).